# Disabling auto input text in html

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I'm building an authentication (username & password) page in html and I want to ensure that the users insert all characters of their username/password combination (no copy&past, autocomplete, etc...)

But I have a problem with password manager extensions (ex. lastpass). How do I prevent them to auto write the username/password?

Comment: Maybe he is required to do such things by law, e.g. "reasonable efforts to protect sensitive data" or so.

Comment: @ThiefMaster This is a keystroke dynamics based authentication system. So if you don't type your password manually, the system will not work. This is not a decision, is a requiment.

Answer (score 1):

autocomplete can be prevented using html5

to make sure your html document is html use the following doctype

To make a input field preventing autocomplete:

```
<input type="password" name="passw" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've have already tried that, but lastpass continues to autoinsert the username/password...